# Spring boot validation only working with @valid:

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-validation

My Spring Boot validation only works if I use the annotation like this (I use Kotlin):

```
@valid:NotEmpty(message = "Please enter a value")
```

So for example:

```
data class RandomDto(
    @valid:NotEmpty(message = "Please enter a value")
    var randomValue: String
)
```

If I use this it won't work:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter a value")
```

Why is this? I annotated the controller function parameter with `@Valid`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a dependency issue. make sure to add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I already have exactly this in my pom.xml. Thank you for replying though.